# how to solve bad topology on this model?

Tags: bevel

[image]i have a class, topology bevel ends good there, when i try to do exactly the same in my file, topology goes wrong, what could i do?
class
[image]

[image]

solved it, dissolved extra vertices and joined using J
[image]

Comment: You have a class? What do you mean?

Comment: Have you checked if the normals are correct on your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dissolved extra vertices and joined using <kbd>J</kbd>